# Google gears a good solution for online/offline wiki?

Tags: wiki, offline, google-gears

we need an online offline wiki type app that is basically a number of pages with documentation in, but that also would need to link to a number of files .. words docs/ pdfs/ ppts etc that are on a synched mapped drive on the users laptop..

could anyone suggest whether or not google gears would be a reasonable solution to this, i have just had a brief peruse on the gears documentation.. and its seems pretty cool/useful.

as in make a web wiki and gears it up.
the app would also need some way of holding the links to the actual files (docs/pdfs etc) but that should impact the gearsiness of it i imagine)

thanks...

sorry its late in the day so the question may not actually make any sense..

nat

Answer (score 5):

Given that Google is publicly committed to supporting HTML 5 and it's very extensive offline application capabilities, I would personally choose that direction over Gears.

Neither Gears nor HTML 5 is going to give you any ability to read content off of the computer. Web browsers are intentionally sand-boxed to prevent that kind of activity.

Check out the [remarkable capabilities of HTML 5](http://apirocks.com/html5/html5.html), and then see [how extensive support for it already is](http://html5demos.com/).

Comment: hi

thanks for the reply.. i hadnt looked at html5 at all.. but the wiki doesnt actually need to store the documents, just be able to link to them, as they are effectively on the users computer .. always in the same place on their W drive or the like.. 
so the offlineyness is just for the navigating to these files .. hopefully in a somewhat whizzy manner..

Answer (score 4):

Gears is for allowing web pages to store local content and applications on a client computer for offline mode, not for allowing the web browser to peek out on the user's computer.

Gears is also deprecated in favor of HTML5 local storage and other developments.